# She must be tripping

Tags: geography, cryptic-crosswords

<sub>This is part 7 of the puzzle series that started at [Living the traveller's dream](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109775/living-the-traveller-s-dream). Each part is solvable on its own.</sub>

---

[image]

> *Dear Puzzling,*
>
> As you have probably noticed, I visit quite a lot of different places and do a lot of different things each week. Even so, there are always places that I could have added to my trip if I had had even more time and energy to spare. Sometimes I keep a list of places I would still have liked to see in case I visit the same place some time in the future. Maybe at the end of this series I’ll share some of my favourite spots that I did not get a chance to visit this time around. Stay tuned for that!
>
> Each puzzle has five "thematic" answers, which are geographical locations all in the same country. Each is notable enough to have its own article in the English Wikipedia, although not necessarily under the same name I use. Your task is to fill the grid, highlight the thematic entries, and guess which country I am currently visiting (which is not indicated in the grid). Some of the answers will be needed in the final part of the series. Except for the last part, all others are solvable on their own without knowledge of the previous puzzles.
>
> This week I have seen mountains covered in lush rainforest, walked inside the walls of a 17th-century military installment, toured an old city centre dating back to the colonial era, and taken a swim in clean pitch-black water. Can you guess where I am?
>
> Wish you were here!
> Love, Gladys.

**Across**
1/3. Stream described by tribesman wearing cloak, swimming (4,5)
6. Hybrid band: "Jazz with two feet" (4)
9. In corrupt fashion, bar elected to be distinguished (10)
11. Remaining sinister socialists abandoned (4)
13. New, Lyon-produced fabric (5)
14. In Vanuatu, a tarantula is an iconic animal (7)
17. Greek princess captured by perverted nun community (5)
19. Work a long time to produce *Porgy and Bess*? (5)
21/22. Deutsches Institut's leaders mistreated Lidl and caused damage (3,3)
23. Tribe trained a rabid dog, perhaps (5)
24. President Saddam – violently ousted dictatorial leader (5)
25. Retrospective broadcast, for example in African country (7)
27. Island in the Aegean Sea surrounds one (eastern†) side of Greek vendor's booth (5)
31. Keys for Airbus's rear a flyer returned (4)
32. Generalised belief of Potter's eye moving (10)
33. Glance at castle from the back (4)
34. Betray angry hybrid (5)
35. Philosopher Plato finally following Far Eastern school of thought (4)

**Down**
1. Cuckoo perhaps throwing out large chicken (4)
2. Laughing and leisurely on vacation, getting candy (5)
4. Not fully prepared to study (4)
5. Aeroplane having a bit of crisis after engineers' leader's exit from aircraft? (5)
7. *(See 16 down)*
8. Eccentric, openly LGBT filmmaker John starting in Hollywood (10)
10. British RMS *Titanic*'s ultimate doom: taking fluid snow for ice mountain (10)
12. A part of sheep (a ram!) – A rib offered to seat of government (10)
15. Actor Raul supported by alliance on highest point of Pike's Peak (10)
16/7. New Zealand tie for military construction (4,9)
18. A book needs introduction; before that, I'll say "impossible to read" (9)
20. Old West lawman is pear-shaped, all wrong (4)
26. Adjust part of church for singers (5)
28. Type of messy place with little walls (5)
29. In Athens' surroundings, ultimately war incarnate (4)
30. Some insane Roman? (4)

<sub>† This erroneously said "western" originally and was fixed after the fact. Thanks to oAlt for pointing it out.</sub>

---

Gladys will return in *[Almost interplanetary travel](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110657/almost-interplanetary-travel)*.

Comment: Halfway through this series. The finale will actually be the 50th Gladys puzzle in total (the first series was 26 parts, the second 10, and this one will be 14).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Edited to reflect changes made in the question]

The completed crossword:

> [image: Completed crossword grid]

Clue explanations:

Across

> 1/3. Stream described by tribesman wearing cloak, swimming (4,5)
>  **COLA CREEK** CLOA(CREE)K*
>
>  6. Hybrid band: "Jazz with two feet" (4)
>  **DZHO** .D .Z .H .O
>
>  9. In corrupt fashion, bar elected to be distinguished (10)
>  **CELEBRATED** BARELECTED*
>
>  11. Remaining sinister socialists abandoned (4)
>  **LEFT** quadruple definition
>
>  13. New, Lyon-produced fabric (5)
>  **NYLON** N + LYON*
>
>  14. In Vanuatu, a tarantula is an iconic animal (7)
>  **TUATARA** .TU A TARA.
>
>  17. Greek princess captured by perverted nun community (5)
>  **UNION** NU(IO)N*
>
>  19. Work a long time to produce Porgy and Bess? (5)
>  **OPERA** OP + ERA
>
>  21/22. Deutsches Institut's leaders mistreated Lidl and caused damage (3,3)
>  **DID ILL** D. I. + LIDL*
>
>  23. Tribe trained a rabid dog, perhaps (5)
>  **BITER** TRIBE*
>
>  24. President Saddam – violently ousted dictatorial leader (5)
>  **ADAMS** SA(-d.)DAM* (John Adams, 2nd person to be president of US)
>
>  25. Retrospective broadcast, for example in African country (7)
>  **NIGERIA** (AIR + EG + IN)<
>
>  27. Island in the Aegean Sea surrounds one (eastern) side of Greek vendor's booth (5)
>  **KIOSK** K(I)OS + .K
>
>  31. Keys for Airbus's rear a flyer returned (4)
>  **TABS** (.S + BAT)<
>
>  32. Generalised belief of Potter's eye moving (10)
>  **STEREOTYPE** POTTERSEYE*
>
>  33. Glance at castle from the back (4)
>  **PEEK** KEEP<
>
>  34. Betray angry hybrid (5)
>  **CROSS** triple definition
>
>  35. Philosopher Plato finally following Far Eastern school of thought (4)
>  **ZENO** ZEN + .O

Down

> 1. Cuckoo perhaps throwing out large chicken (4)
>  **COCK** C(-l)OCK
>
>  2. Laughing and leisurely on vacation, getting candy (5)
>  **LOLLY** LOL + L.Y
>
>  4. Not fully prepared to study (4)
>  **READ** READ(-y)
>
>  5. Aeroplane having a bit of crisis after engineers' leader's exit from aircraft? (5)
>  **EJECT** E. + JE(C.)T
>
>  7. (See 16 down)
>
>  8. Eccentric, openly LGBT filmmaker John starting in Hollywood (10)
>  **OUTLANDISH** OUT + LANDIS (John Landis) + H.
>
>  10. British RMS Titanic's ultimate doom: taking fluid snow for ice mountain (10)
>  **BROWNSBERG** BR + (ice -> SNOW*)BERG
>
>  12. A part of sheep (a ram!) – A rib offered to seat of government (10)
>  **PARAMARIBO** .P A RAM A RIB O.
>
>  15. Actor Raul supported by alliance on highest point of Pike's Peak (10)
>  **JULIANATOP** JULIA (Raul Julia) + NATO + P.
>
>  16/7. New Zealand tie for military construction (4,9)
>  **FORT ZEELANDIA** ZEALANDTIEFOR*
>
>  18. A book needs introduction; before that, I'll say "impossible to read" (9)
>  **ILLEGIBLE** I'LL + EG + (-b)IBLE
>
>  20. Old West lawman is pear-shaped, all wrong (4)
>  **EARP** PEAR* (Wyatt Earp)
>
>  26. Adjust part of church for singers (5)
>  **ALTER** "altar" homophone
>
>  28. Type of messy place with little walls (5)
>  **STYLE** STY + L.E
>
>  29. In Athens' surroundings, ultimately war incarnate (4)
>  **ARES** &lit, A(.R .E)S
>
>  30. Some insane Roman? (4)
>  **NERO** &lit, .NE RO.

This time, Gladys visited

> **Suriname**, where [Cola Creek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cola_Creek) (1/3 across), [Brownsberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownsberg) (10 down), [Paramaribo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramaribo) (12 down), [Julianatop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julianatop) (15 down), and [Fort Zeelandia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Zeelandia_(Paramaribo)) (16/7 down) are located.

There were three things unclear to me, but those were answered by OP in a comment below this answer (and for the third thing, OP edited the question). Anyway, here were my initial questions:

> 1) For 31 across, is the intention that Tab is a key on the keyboard?
>  2) I'm not completely certain about the wordplay of 10 down; I've never seen BR before to mean "British RMS".
>  3) For 27 across, shouldn't "western" be "eastern"? Or am I supposed to interpret that as "K(I)OS is on the western side"?

Comment: 1: Yeah, meant keyboard keys there. 2: rot13(Oe. vf Oevgvfu, gur EZF orybatf gb gur arkg cneg. Nygubhtu V fhccbfr vg pbhyq whfg nf jryy unir orra yrsg bhg.) 3: Argh yes, I mixed up west and east again. Sorry about that!

Comment: Ah, re: 2 I should have remembered that usage :D

Comment: Fixed 27a with a comment. Not a good look in a geography-themed puzzle to forget which direction is which!